# Easily getting rid of items

Tags: ingress

I'm hitting the 2000 items limit. I find it very time consuming to drop or recycle every item with 3 taps. The easiest way to get rid of xmps is to just fire them. But what about the other item types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any.

There's no way around the recycle time limit that won't get you banned fairly quickly.
I tend to just blindly recycle (and watch the phone screen from the corner of my eye) while I'm reading or watching a video or something.

You can drop items reasonably quickly if your phone is fast enough; my trick is to hover the right middle finger above Ops, the left thumb over the screen center, and the right thumb over Drop. Then touch the three in sequence, with just the right speed.

Unfortunately, that leaves them around for the opposition to use … so maybe you'd rather recycle, and use the resulting XM for recharging …?

Comment: It also makes sense to just mass-fire lower level bursters, either at random or for example while taking the bus or sitting in someone's car. Never play while you are driving yourself though! Firing is quicker than recycling or dropping, and shooting the low stuff at a large number of enemy ports while going past them tickles the opposing faction and makes them come running. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since July (version 1.55.2 if I am correct) the **multi-recycle** feature was aded. You can select the item type you want to dispose of and the amount to recycle. You get previewed with the XM amount you can claim with the recycling

Comment: They should develop a different recycling method for just 1-2 items, though. This multi-recycle feature is killing us on low count items whilst driving through a dense portal area if your inventory is full.